# Getting substring from sqlreader return value

Tags: vb.net

So I get values from a database and based on that we encode a XML file. But the data we get back from the database is  "12454 testing". But I would only like the numbers and encode them.

```
   Dim oDoc As New FormDB
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = oDoc.GetSingleDocument(SB_ID)

    While dr.Read
        Dim outdoc As String = "<ns0:TEST xmlns:ns0='http://Prototype.Test'>" & _

   "<CostCode>" & Encode(dr.Item("COSTCODE")) & "</CostCode>" & _
 "</ns0:TEST >"
```

So how do i only encode the the number "21334" in the costCode tags, Dont want to encode "144343 testing".

Thanks

Comment: Regex: **\d+** that's one way... Show us what you have **tried** and maybe you will get another suggestion or solution perhaps...

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted but I guess it could be my understanding of what is being asked. Or perhaps it's an understanding of how this can be done with the dr.Item() value. I made an assumption that Encode was a method to remove the text from the value being read. The Answer was an example of how to split a string inline. I think the issue is that dr.Item("CostCode") is an object and Option Strict being off is allowing the code to execute. See my updated answer for a more concise example or explain why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String.Split() inline. For example, if you had something like:

```
Dim myStr = "123456 SomeText"
```

you could use it inside another string to get only the numbers with something like

```
Dim newStr = "<ProductID>" & myStr.Split(" "c)(0) & "</ProductID>"
```

Giving you the result `<ProductID>123456</ProductID>` where using 1 in place of the 0 would give you `<ProductID>SomeText</ProductID>`

EDIT:
With Option Strict Off the compiler is not warning you about the use of `dr.Item("COSTCODE")` being an object and not a string. We can overcome this by using the .ToString method to give us access to the Split extension method.

```
Dim oDoc As New FormDB
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = oDoc.GetSingleDocument(SB_ID)

While dr.Read
    Dim outdoc As String = "<ns0:TEST xmlns:ns0='http://Prototype.Test'>" & _
"<CostCode>" & dr.Item("COSTCODE").ToString.Split(" "c)(0) & "</CostCode>" & _
"</ns0:TEST >"
```

Again, this code is expecting the reader (dr) to be bringing in a string of text like  "12454 testing" and is only taking the 12454 and injecting it into your outdoc string. The output when the reader reads in  "12454 testing" would be:

```
<ns0:TEST xmlns:ns0='http://Prototype.Test'><CostCode>12454</CostCode></ns0:TEST >
```

Which was my understanding of what was needed from what was being read in.